# Make first word second with jQuery? And Remove 3rd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have the following code:

```
<div>December Friday the 12th</div>
```

I need to change it to: Friday, December 12th

This is generated dynamically, though the format will be consistent. I can not edit the markup. How can I move this words with jQuery?

Comment: Not sure how to target the words, since they don't have any markup to differentiate them.

Comment: its seems to me the real question is how do I target divs containing the date strings

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fix the date formatting code that generated this text?

Comment: @Sparky, read the question. it's not an option.

Comment: I read your question and my _comment_ stands.  Despite the fact that you claim you _"can not edit the markup"_, does not have anything to do with the fact that fixing the server-side code would be the ideal solution.

Comment: "Wouldn't the world be a better place if trees were made of Gummi Bears? " Though true, your statement is not useful or relevant to my question.

Comment: His statement is relevant to the question. He's saying can you modify the server-side code? That doesn't necessarily mean changing some HTML file. Don't be rude to people trying to help you.

Comment: @MikeC if OP had shown even an attempt the comments wouldn't be so severe. This is not a difficult issue to research

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can done it by `split()`. Convert text to array using `split()` then format by array index. Example:

```js
var val = $('div').text().split(' '),
    newText = val[1] + ', ' + val[0] + ' ' + val[3];
    $('div').text(newText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>December Friday the 12th</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.split()` and `.text()`.

```
$('div').text(function (index, txt) {
  var arr = txt.split(' ');
  return arr[1] + ', ' + arr[0] + ' ' + arr[3];
});
```